# How to get documents from Firestore in chronological order across multiple queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a chronological feed, which shows posts of users I follow.
I get the posts from Firestore, but they are not ordered, because they are fetched in different chunks and only each chunk is ordered. Also I don't really want to order the posts later.

I think I need a better way to fetch the data, but I don't know how.
Can somebody help me?

Thanks!

```js
fetchPostsFromFollows: builder.query<any,
      { followedUsers: string[]; postsPerLoad: number }
    >({
      async queryFn(arg) {
        const { followedUsers, postsPerLoad } = arg;
        let usersArray = [...followedUsers, auth.currentUser.uid];
        try {
          const chunkSize = 10;
          const followedUsersChunk = usersArray.reduce(
            (resultArray, item, index) => {
              const chunkIndex = Math.floor(index / chunkSize);

              if (!resultArray[chunkIndex]) {
                resultArray[chunkIndex] = []; // start a new chunk
              }

              resultArray[chunkIndex].push(item);

              return resultArray;
            },
            []
          );

          let postArray = [];
          for await (const snap of followedUsersChunk.map(async (chunk) => {
            const postRef = query(
              collectionGroup(db, "userPosts"),
              where("userId", "in", chunk),
              orderBy("timestamp", "desc"),
              limit(2)
            );
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(postRef);
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              postArray.push({
                timestamp: doc
                  .data()
                  ["timestamp"].toDate()
                  .toLocaleDateString("de-DE", dateFormatShort),
                body: doc.data().body,
                userId: doc.data().userId,
                id: doc.id,
              });
            });
          }));

          return { data: postArray };
        } catch (err) {
          return { error: err };
        }
      },
      providesTags: ["Posts"],
    }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're retrieving the posts for each user in turn. So while you get the posts for *each* user chronologically, they may not be ordered chronologically across *all* users.

---

If you have fewer than 30 user IDs, you can pass them all to the `in` clause of your query in one go, and thus get all posts ordered. Note that this [limit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations) was recently increased from 10 to 30, and it looks like you still need to update your code for that.

If you have more than 30 users, then with your current data model there is no other option than loading then in chunks and re-ordering the documents in your application code.

---

An alternative is to change your data model to suit your use-case, a common consideration when using NoSQL databases. Here for example, you could duplicate the data for each post to each follower into a dedicated collection (e.g. `userFeed`), when someone writes a post. This way the write operation will take longer, and you'll have lots of duplicate data, but then to read the feed for the current user, you can now query a single collection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Didn't know about the increased limit. That could solve my problem for now and than I can try to implement your second suggestion.
It's just a side project, so lots of learning and trying new things out  :)